# Linear program with double constraints on the same variable

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I have a linear program of the form min(f*x) s.t. A1*x < d1; A2*x < d2. The form with one constraint is implemented in Matlab in command [linprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html). What command can I use to solve linear program with two constrraints?

I could of course create a block diagonal matrix, and double the size of the variable x, but if there is more efficient way I would like to use it, because the size of the matrix is quite large.

Comment: I think your only option is to create a block diagonal matrix.  I haven't seen anything in the optimization toolbox that can handle multiple constraints in the way you're specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I don't understand the question right but can't you combine the matrixes `A1` und `A2` by `A = [A1; A2]`?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe interested in [Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition) algorithm for solving linear programming. It takes advantage of this block diagonal structure. However, I don't think there is an out-of-the box implementation of it in commercial softwares.